# OracleClient to devart dotConnect for Oracle

Tags: oracle, ado.net, oracleclient, devart, dotconnect

Has anyone tried migration from Microsoft OracleClient to dotConnect for Oracle? Is it realy so easy (as they wrote at their blog http://www.devart.com/blogs/dotconnect/?p=67) or just another marketing trick?
I've tried ODP.NET, but it seems to me that its interface differs from the standard one.

Comment: Yes, the interface of Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand differs from System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand. This is quit normal, because odp.net offers much more features and support of oracle native types. **But** both implement the System.Data.Common.DbCommand as standard interface.

Answer (score 4):

I have used the devart dotConnect for oracle provider for a couple of years and it works fine.

The main advantage (to me anyway) is that you do not have to install an oracle client on the machines you deploy your solution to. It is also offers better performance than the oracle client in some cases.

In addition you get support for both Linq to Oracle and the entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

Granted that I've only been using DevArt dotConnect for only about a month, and never do any provider migration, but from what I see, it's going to be a trivial task.